# Continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ that is constant on $X$, is also constant on $\overline{X}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that when $Z$ is a normed space, and $\overline{X}\subset Z$, $Y\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$, $f:Z\rightarrow Y$ a continuous function which is constant on all of $X$, it is also constant on the closure of $X$, $\overline{X}$.

My attempt: Let $f(x)=0\text{ for all }x\in X$. Then, by continuity, we know that $\forall x\in X\,\forall\varepsilon>0\,\exists\,\delta>0\,\forall y\in X\, |x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ (where $|\cdot|$ is the norm corresponding to the normed space $Z$) Now, take $y\in \partial X$ and $x\in X$ a $\delta$ away from this $y$. Then $f(x),f(y)$ need to be arbitrarily closed, since $f(x)=0$, it follows that $f(y)=0$.

The issue I have with this is, can't we keep extending this until the function is constant everywhere? (Thus then also $f:Z\rightarrow Y$ would be constant as well.)

Any help/suggestions if the assumption in the first line is correct/my attempt on proving it are very welcome! (For context, I'm trying to prove something on annihilators in Functional Analysis)

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: What is $|x-y|$?

Comment: Well, actually I now realize for my problem, I am seeing X has a normed space and $Y=\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$, which makes $|\cdot |$ actually an arbitrary norm.

Comment: It's not correct if $X$. Take $f(x)=0$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$. Then $f$ is continuous on $X:=\mathbb R^*$, but not on $\overline{X}$.

Comment: What if $f:Z\rightarrow Y$ was continuous, and $X\subset Z$ with $f(x)=0, \forall x\in X$?

Comment: That is indeed different... and indeed works if $\overline{X}\subset Z$ (otherwise it not works)

Comment: @JackpotWizard180 the crucial question is if $f$ is continuous on the closure of $X$ too or not. Even more so, is it defined on the closure of $X$?

Comment: @AnCar, if we assume $\overline{X}\subset Z$ and $f:Z\rightarrow Y$ is continuous on all of $Z$, $f(x)=0 \forall \,x\in X$

Comment: I edited the question, sorry for it being so incomplete the first time.

Comment: Ah then yes. Let $x_0\in \overline{X}\setminus X$. Pick $\varepsilon>0$ and look at the ball around $x_0$ with radius $\varepsilon$. This intersects $X$ by definition, so you can take a sequence of points $\{x_n\}$ in the intersection converging to $x_0$. By continuity of $f$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=f(x_0)$, so $f(x_0)$ has the same value as $f$ on $X$.

Comment: Crucially, as was pointed above by @Surb, this fails if you just assume that $f$ is continuous on $X$ and not on $\overline{X}$.

Comment: Your proof is a bit sloppy. Suppose $f(x)=c$ for all $x\in X$. Let $u\in \overline{X}$ and $(x_n)$ a sequence of $X$ that converges to $u$. Then $f(x_n)=c$ for all $n$, and thus, by continuity, $$f(u)=\lim_{n\to \infty }f(x_n)=c.$$

Comment: Ah yes, thank you all! Working with sequences to show the desired result works better. But couldn't we now extend this until $f$ is constant on all of $Z$, by repeatedly choosing a point outside of the closure of $X$ within an $\varepsilon$ radius? I'm pretty sure that shouldn't work, but don't know how to show that.

Comment: of course not ! If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ continuous, and $f(x)=0$ on $(0,1)$, if $X=(0,1)$ and $Z=\mathbb R$, there is no reason that $f(x)=0$ on $\mathbb R$. However, if $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is constant on some connected open set, then it will be constant on $\mathbb R$...

Comment: @JackpotWizard180 no. Consider $Z=[0,2]$ and let $f(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in[1,2]$. Set $X=(1,2]$. Then $f$ is clearly continuous on $[0,2]$, constant on $X$, constant on $\overline{X}=[1,2]$, but not on $Z$.

Comment: Yea I figured it wasn't possible (by reasoning then every function could be made constant), and I was thinking of proving it, but a counterexample is way quicker of course, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

No, in general, it is not possible for any arbitrary set $Z$ containing $X$, the largest $Z$ you can choose is $Z= \bar{X}$.